# Error installing windows remote desktop app using powershell as per-device using -allusers option

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I am having problems installing the msi for the windows remote desktop app using powershell as per-device.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/windowsdesktop-admin
Per device installation only requires ALLUSERS=1 option.
This works `msiexec.exe /I 'C:\ITS\RemoteDesktop_1.2.3213.0_x64.msi' /qn /l*v C:\ITS\RemoteDesktop119.log`
This errors with error status: 1603 `msiexec.exe /I 'C:\ITS\RemoteDesktop_1.2.3213.0_x64.msi' /qn ALLUSERS=1 /l*v C:\ITS\RemoteDesktop119.log`
Just above error, Return value 3 there are some rubbish characters in the Public Desktop Path.
**Error 1606. Could not access network location ΓÇ£C:\Users\Public\DesktopΓÇ¥\Desktop.**

Answer (score 0):

This was not an issue with the MSI rather a 3rd party app that was overwriting data in **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders**